# Conditional alloc/dealloc? [Objective-c and Cocos2D]

Tags: objective-c, conditional-statements, release, dealloc, alloc

What if I want to alloc a class inside another and I want to reference it easily, but sometimes this class would not need to be alloc'd, therefore not dealloc'd. How is this done? Can I put a conditional inside dealloc so it doesn't have to be released?

In more detail, I'm using Cocos2D. I have player ability classes that may or may not need to be allocated. In my init:

```
    // Abilities
    if(abilityRushH == 0){
        objects = [theMap objectGroupNamed:@"oj"];
        startPoint = [objects objectNamed:@"item_ability_rushH"];
        x = [[startPoint valueForKey:@"x"] intValue];
        y = [[startPoint valueForKey:@"y"] intValue];

        rushH = [[RushHorizontal alloc] init];

        [self addChild:rushH.rushHSpriteSheet];

        rushH.rushHSprite.position = ccp(x,y);              
    }

    if(abilityRushV == 0){
        objects = [theMap objectGroupNamed:@"oj"];
        startPoint = [objects objectNamed:@"item_ability_rushV"];
        x = [[startPoint valueForKey:@"x"] intValue];
        y = [[startPoint valueForKey:@"y"] intValue];

        rushV = [[RushVertical alloc] init];

        [self addChild:rushV.rushVSpriteSheet];

        rushV.rushVSprite.position = ccp(x,y);  
    }
```

Cocos2D needs to keep the reference so it can scroll with the map.  But if I'm not alloc'ing it, how do I NOT dealloc?

Comment: What do you mean by `Cocos2D` needs to keep the reference? Does it instantiate the variable for its own purpose?

Comment: Yeah.  If I were to release rushH and rushV right after I set the positions, the game will start fine, but if I move the map, it will crash immediately.  No where in my own code am I referencing those objects until the player collides with them on the map, so Cocos2D must be using references of them to make rushH and rushV move with the map.

Comment: Why don't you check if `rushH` and `rushV` are `nil` before you allocate them? Log them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are talking of releasing it in `dealloc`, there will be an instance variable for this. Now when any instance of an Objective-C class is allocated, all its objects are `nil` and c types are set to 0 (or equivalent values). So you don't need to put any extra effort if the object of your class isn't instantiated as the instance variable will be `nil` at `dealloc` and so `release` message sent to it will have no effect.

Comment: So are you saying if I don't alloc an object but release it in dealloc with the same name, it will have no effect?

Comment: Yes. This is true for instance variables and not method variables. Method variables are not `nil` by default. Instance variables are.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the optional variable is nil when its not needed, and do a nil check before dealloc'ing.

Comment: The `nil` check is unnecessary -- it's safe to send a `release` message to `nil`.

Comment: You could do that ... I consider it sloppy code and avoid it whenever possible.

Comment: Yeah but then you're just adding more code that does nothing, right?